# Deploying an ECS application to AWS using docker compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I am following the [AWS tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/) on deploying an ECS application using `docker compose`.

**When I run `docker compose up`, I only receive the message `docker  UpdateInProgress User Initiated`, but nothing else happens:**

```
[+] Running 0/0
 - docker  UpdateInProgress User Initiated                                                                 0.0s
```

Previously, this worked fine and all the ECS resources (cluster, task definitions, services, load balancer) had been created.

For some reason, now, this does not work anymore (although I have not changed my *docker-compose.yml* file).

*docker-compose.yml:*

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: ${AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY}/postgres
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    
  server:
    image: ${AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY}/server
    networks:
      - my-network
    env_file:
    - .env
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    depends_on:
    - postgres
    entrypoint: "/server/run.sh"
    
  pgadmin:
    image: ${AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY}/pgadmin
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
    - postgres
    volumes:
       - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}"
    
networks:
  my-network:
    #driver: bridge
    
    
volumes:
    postgres:
    pgadmin:
```

I also switched to the correct Docker context before (`docker context use my-aws-context`).
And I have updated to the latest version of Docker Desktop for Windows and AWS CLI.

Did someone already have a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the message it appears that you are trying to compose up a stack that is existing already (on AWS) and so it's trying to update the CFN stack. Can you check if this is the case? You have a couple of options if that is what's happening: 1) delete the CFN stack (either in AWS or with `docker compose down`) or 2) launch the `docker compose up` with the flag `--project-name string` (where `string` is an arbitrary name of your choice). By default compose will use the directory name as the project name so if you compose up twice it will try to work on the same stack.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, apparently, AWS got caught in a broken state. So `docker compose down` helped me to destroy all resources, so that I could recreate them again.